# Craft 404 for admin dashboard

Tags: 404

OK, I have encountered the following issue:

**Issue:**
 Admin page gets a Craft 404 page error; home page loads fine though.

- Home page: `192.168.10.95`
  [image]
- Admin page: `http://192.168.10.95/public/index.php/admin/dashboard`
  [image]

Clearly Craft is working, though I am not sure what is causing this to break for me. Any suggestions?  I can provide any information you may want to see, just let me know.

Thank you Craft friends!

**Edit 03/14/2017 @08:24 PST**

Here is the contents of my `/etc/apache2/sites-availavble/000-default.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I have pointed my DocumentRoot to `/var/www/html/public`, though did I miss something in my configuration?

Thanks again Craft friends!

Comment: It looks like your document root is incorrect. It should point to the `public` directory, so the admin URL will be `http://192.168.10.95/admin`

Comment: Hello and thank you @stephen, are you referring to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` OR `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` ?

Comment: The former. It should contain a [`DocumentRoot` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot).

Comment: @StephenLewis I believe I have that setup already, unless I missed something else in my configuration?

Comment: So have you tried visiting `http://192.168.10.95/admin`?

Comment: Wowzers! No, I never thought to try `192.168.10.95/admin`; that's how I know I have been working to long on this project. Thank you for such a simple answer - at least for the 404 on the admin page.
Super sheepish feeling here. Thank you very much @StephenLewis !!

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I am "*to close to the painting*" here and completely missed a simple answer. In my case, I was going to the wrong URL completely.

Bad: `http://192.168.10.95/public/index.php/admin/dashboard`

Good: `http://192.168.10.95/admin`

As you can see, ***USER*** error here. Thank you for the assistance everyone!